# Updating Screen pixel colors using a random generated vector color

Tags: c++, opengl

I have divided my display circle to 16 segments. I need to update each segment reading a randomly generated vector of colors. every segment of my circle is 22.5, which is 100 * 360 circle = 2250 pixels. 
As I searched the function I shall use is glDrawPixels(). Though, I am not sure yet.
Could you get me a sample code to understand how I could generate my vectors of colors and update my circle segment 2250 pixel using this vector please. Besides, I don't know where to start updating the segment, is it real or it will be updated as texture!

I also used this code, but gives segmentation fault:

```
void GlWidget::displayColors()
{
    //Create some nice colours (3 floats per pixel) from data -10..+10
    int size = 2250;
    float* pixels = new float[size*3];

      for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
          pixels[0] = 1;
                   pixels[1] = 1;
                             pixels[2] = 1;
      }

      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      glDrawPixels(width(),height(),GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixels);

    //  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: "Solutions" go in the "Answer" section below. It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: @user1596226: Your question is extraordinarily difficult to follow. What does, "every segment of my circle is 22.5," mean? What does "100 * 360 circle" mean? What does "update my circle segment 2250 pixel" mean? Perhaps if you draw a picture or two of what you're describing, it'll become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely difficult to understand what you are trying to do, but I'll offer a general piece of advice…

On most platforms, OpenGL is a hardware accelerated, and is so much faster than simply blitting pixels to display memory, that rendering a partial screen is almost never necessary. There are rare exceptions, but you should only consider doing so if you have a performance problem that optimising your OpenGL pipeline doesn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing 100 circles is barely going to tax the GPU at all. It sounds like this is a premature optimisation.  I strongly suggest you undertake a proper performance analysis before making your code significantly more complex in trying to do what you describe.

It sounds like you're trying to optimise the drawing by only rendering the part of the display that has changed. This is a common optimisation method on buffer-backed displays in GUI systems. However, it is not the norm when rendering with OpenGL.  Usually you would render the entire scene for each frame.

Furthermore, `glReadPixels()` is a *very* expensive operation.  It basically stalls the rendering pipeline and reads back the render buffer from the GPU into main memory, which is relatively slow.  It is almost certainly not what you want to do.

If you *really* need to optimise the drawing, you could cache your drawing into a texture and just render the texture in a quad each frame.  But first, make sure that it is really worth the extra effort and complexity.

There are some good books and online resources around on OpenGL and performance analysis. It is definitely worth doing some research to save yourself some time before you try to save yourself some time. :)

Comment: but if I want to update the pixels from an array of colors, I should use glDrawPixels and not glRealPixels, isn't that correct?

Comment: `glDrawPixels` is part of the old raster API, so almost certainly not. Even if you already have pre-rendered pixmaps, you'd just render a texture. What platform and OpenGL version are you using? It sounds like there's some confusion about actually rendering the circle. If you want to fill a circle with different colours, you can look at a triangle fan.